# XSLT split one long string value delimited by comma

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an input xml which has this

```
<BankStatementAccount>
    <Line>
        <Data>TEST,,TEST,,,</Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>,,,,,</Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>Account:,TEST,TEST,,,</Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>,,,,,</Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>Payment Date:,1/5/2019,,,,</Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>,,,,,</Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>Payment No:,123456,,,,</Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>,,,,,</Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>11/01/19,crnote,088-543215432,(48.47),(3.39),(45.08)
        </Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>05/02/19,crnote,033-123456789,(10.09),(0.71),(9.38)
        </Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>,,,,,</Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>,,Amount Paid,"133,654.70","9,356.10 ","124,298.60 "
        </Data>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Data>,,,,,</Data>
    </Line>
</BankStatementAccount>
```

Each `<Line>` string value has 6 data values separated by 5 commas.
I need to be able to split them on their own individual tags.

To look something like this:

From : `<Line>05/02/19,cr note,033-123456789,(10.09),(0.71),(9.38)</Line>`

To :

```
<Line> 
    <tag1>05/02/19</tag1>
    <tag2>cr note</tag2>
    <tag3>033-123456789</tag3>
    <tag4>(10.09)</tag4>
    <tag5>(0.71)</tag5>
    <tag6>(9.38)</tag6>
</Line>
```

I tried,

```
<BankStatementAccount>
    <xsl:for-each select="BankStatementAccount/Line">
        <Line>
            <xsl:value-of select="Data" />
            <xsl:variable name="var" select="substring(.,1,8)" />
            <tag1><xsl:value-of select="$var[1]" /></tag1>
            <!-- and $var[2].. so on.. -->
        </Line>
    </xsl:for-each>
</BankStatementAccount>
```

but I keep getting this error

> FATAL ERROR:  'Error checking type of the expression
>   'filter-expr(variable-ref(var/string), [pred(int-expr(1))])'.'

I tried substring(.,1,8) to see first if I'll get characters from position 1 - 8 but I can't seem to run this.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: If your values are comma-separated, then what's point of trying to extract the first 8 characters? You need to **tokenize** the contents of `Data`. Which XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: Please indicate whether you are looking for an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution. The answers will be very different.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a processor that supports XSL 2.0, try something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Line">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(Data, ',')">
            <xsl:element name="tag{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```